# Fourier transform using Dirac's

Tags: fourier-transform, dirac-delta

I'm trying to find the Fourier transform of

$\ f(t) = 25 \cdot \sin(8t + 5) + 13 \cdot \cos(7t-3)$.

I understand that this can somehow be done with Dirac's delta function as a help, I understand the definition of the delta function but I don't know how to actually apply it in this case. If anyone could give me some pointers I'd be grateful!

Comment: As well as your function is periodic Fourier transform of it gives you its Fourier series. Indeed, delta functions will be used to get it. I will publish an answer later.

Answer (score 1):

Let's define the Fourier transform as
\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}\{f(t)\}=F(\omega)=\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }f(t)e^{-i\omega t}\,\mathrm dt
\end{align}
Observing that 
\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}\{\cos(at)\}&=\pi\left[\delta(\omega-a)+\delta(\omega+a)\right]\\
\mathcal{F}\{\sin(at)\}&=-i\pi\left[\delta(\omega-a)-\delta(\omega+a)\right]
\end{align}
we have
\begin{align}
F(\omega)&=-25\,\mathrm e^{i5\omega}i\pi\left[\delta(\omega-8)-\delta(\omega+8)\right]+
13\,\mathrm e^{-i3\omega}\,\pi\left[\delta(\omega-7)+\delta(\omega+7)\right]
\end{align}